# Creating a process from a queue in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I am trying to follow the first example at https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/wiki/Binding-to-asynchronous-processes

Filling in some gaps and adding some debug prints I got to the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.stream.async.mutable.Queue
import scalaz.stream.{Process, Sink}

object ProcessTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scalaz.stream.async

    val q: Queue[Int] = async.unboundedQueue[Int]
    val src: Process[Task, Int] = q.dequeue

    // Thread 1
    val f1 = Future {
      for (i <- 0 to 10) {
        println(s"enqueueOne $i")
        Thread.sleep(100)
        q.enqueueOne(i)
      }
      println("closing")
      q.close
      println("closed")
    }

    // Thread 2
    val f2 = Future {
      val buf = new collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]
      val snk: Sink[Task, Int] = scalaz.stream.io.fillBuffer(buf)
      val run: Task[Unit] = src.map(x => {
        println(s"map $x")
        x
      }).to(snk).run
      println("running")
      run.get.runFor(3.seconds)
      println(s"result = ${buf.toList}")
    }

    Await.result(f1, 10.seconds)
    Await.result(f2, 10.seconds)
  }
}
```

When I try to run this, nothing is received in thread2:

```
enqueueOne 0
running
enqueueOne 1
enqueueOne 2
enqueueOne 3
enqueueOne 4
enqueueOne 5
enqueueOne 6
enqueueOne 7
enqueueOne 8
enqueueOne 9
enqueueOne 10
closing
closed
[error] (run-main-9) java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

What did I do wrong?
Where is this blocking?

(I am using scalaz-stream 0.8.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: `enqueueOne` and `close` return Tasks, which must be run:

```
// Thread 1
val f1 = Future {
  for (i <- 0 to 10) {
    println(s"enqueueOne $i")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    q.enqueueOne(i).run
  }
  println("closing")
  q.close.run
  println("closed")
}
```